# Casperjs keep alive a login session

Tags: javascript, casperjs, headless-browser

I'm trying to keep alive a login session, after 3 min of inactivity the user get disconnected.

The problem here is that most of cases the page is giving errors 502/504, so I want to send http get request every 20/30 secs without receive a response, just to leave a request and keep alive the session.

I want do it but at the same time that I make some stuff on the site, like scrapping, something like a new tab.

There's a way to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the site's content, but if it has any filter (as in show results filter) you could add a step in the script to change that every 20/30 secs, that means you "refresh" the content and the session stays alive.

Other way is adding a GET parameter on the url, let's say your page is `http://www.example.com/infoineed`. Add a step using `thenOpen('http://www.example.com/infoineed?get=donothing')`, this will somehow refresh the page but do nothing.

And finally you can use reload(),once again, this depends on the site you're working on.

Hope it helps, cheers!